# How to parse the IIS ApplicationHost.config file into .Net objects?

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I am writing an app to interrogate what sites are active on an IIS server.  The best way seems to be to directly read the `ApplicationHost.config` file.

What's the easiest way to go about this?

Is it possible to write back a new site using this method also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the ApplicationHost.Config is just an XML, you could use some tool to generate classes from it, something like [Xml2CSharp](http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/). You may need to adapt one thing or another, but it's a start.

Then you deserialize the ApplicationHost.config into objects like a regular XML.

You could directly change the ApplicationHost.config to add sites, application pools and change other configs, but I wouldn't recommend to do so.

You can use the [ServerManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager(v=vs.90).aspx) class. Here you are a very basic sample, so you can start playing around:

```
using(var serverManager = ServerManager.OpenRemote("my-remote-server"))
{
    if (serverManager.Sites.AllowsAdd())
    {
        var site = serverManager.Sites.Add(siteName, path, port);
        // use site for something, like changing its bindings or something else
        serverManager.CommitChanges(); // without this, changes are made only in memory
    }
}
```

Make sure you the application which will execute this code runs under a user which exists in the remote server. The application needs to run in a machine and user account which can remotely access the target IIS server.

Also, you need to add a reference to `Microsoft.Web.Administration`, should be located under c:\windows\system32\inetsrv.

Answer (score 1):

1) ApplicationHost.config is an XML file so you can simply use the XDocument class.

2) Yes - XDocument allows construction of new XML elements.

Answer (score 0):

I generated classes with [Xml2CSharp](http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/) with the applicationHost.config file I had. I also was only interested in bindings per site. The main changes were to correct class and variable names with full stops (system.webServer -> systemwebServer). Stackoverflow won't host uploaded class files and at 815 lines the generated class was a bit long to post. However to get started this may help

```
    JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();

string applicationHostFile = @"C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config\applicationHost.config";

using (System.Xml.XmlTextReader reader = new System.Xml.XmlTextReader(applicationHostFile))
{
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer DeSerializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Xml2CSharp.Configuration));
    Xml2CSharp.Configuration configuration = (Xml2CSharp.Configuration)DeSerializer.Deserialize(reader);

    foreach (var site in configuration.SystemapplicationHost.Sites.Site)
    {
        // clear Application to not expose sensitive information
        site.Application = null;
        Console.WriteLine(site.Name);
        foreach (var binding in site.Bindings.Binding)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(binding.BindingInformation);
        }
    }
}
```